# Material goes wrong when using AO in Base Color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, normals, ambient-occlusion

I met a problem when I render my model. So my model looks like this in Solid mode:
[image]

But when I added material to this and use Ambient Occlusion in Base Color, it looks like this in render preview:
[image]

If I use RGB in Base Color it looks still not very good but doesn't have those shadows:
[image]

Render settings are as followed:
[image]

I already recalculated the normals but still doesn't work. Does anyone know what might be the problem? Thx:)

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: as @moonboots says, please share your file, because this is probably not anything related to render settings, rather it will be shading issue, duplicated vertice(edge), inverted normal or something what is easily resolved

Comment: hey thank you for the answer, I am new here so not really familiar with the forum yet, I will try to upload the file.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/f915f758c742465a8a64519c3cfe12af